# Chrome Network Dev tools not showing all requests

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using this website in a presentation as an example of a single page application: https://www.ca.kayak.com/

(Here I am afraid my post will be flagged as spam or advertisement but it is a specific example for those that want to reproduce a possible issue)

Steps:

- Open the website on both Edge and Chrome.
- Search for hotels in Paris, France.
- It will show you the first set of results.
- Scroll down and click on "More results".
- On Chrome network dev tools we will see this

[image: chrome network result]

- On Microsoft Edge (this is the first time in my life that I am using Microsoft Edge as a good reference for something :D) we will see this:

[image: edge network result]

Those requests named "More" and the number of the pagination "3" (for instance) are empty. The actual content returned is returned on the POST `HotelSearchPoll?p=3` (where 3 is the number of the page).

My question is: is there a way to show these requests on Chrome? Is this a bug?

Comment: Try `chrome://net-export`.